# I'm having trouble explaining runtimes for OpenCL program

Tags: multithreading, runtime, opencl

I have a pathfinder program in both OpenCL code and C#.  I am running it multithreaded on a linux OS to test and compare runtimes for a report I have to write for work.  I really don't fully understand OpenCL so I'm hoping someone can help me.  I've discovered that by increasing threads, the runtime of the C# program increases.  When I do the same to OpenCL the runtime decreases.  I know the runtime is supposed to increase by increasing threads but I'm struggling to explain why the result patterns are different in the two programs?

Any advice is much appreciated.  If I need to provide anymore information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If by "increasing threads" in OpenCL you mean increasing the global workgroup size, that will increase the amount of work you do, and thus will increase the runtime. There really is no way to increase the number of threads in OpenCL. The implicit assumption is that you want all of them. What you do specify is the dimensions of your work, and the GPU will spread it out across its available execution units.